# I want to know how to make this .live() in jquery

Tags: jquery

i was wondering how i could get this to be live? I have a text box that is fetched via ajax, and its excluding already loaded scripts i have cause of the dom I'm assuming. Any who, I've played with .live() but i usually have an element to hook it to ex/ `$('blah').live();`,  but i found myself scratching my head on this one lol

```
(function($) {

$.fn.charCount = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {    
        allowed: 140,       
        warning: 25,
        css: 'counter',
        counterElement: 'span',
        cssWarning: 'warning',
        cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
        counterText: ''
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

    function calculate(obj){
        var count = $(obj).val().length;
        var available = options.allowed - count;
        if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
            $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
        } else {
            $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
        }
        if(available < 0){
            $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
        } else {
            $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
        }
        $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
    };

    this.each(function() {              
        $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
        calculate(this);
        $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this)});
        $(this).change(function(){calculate(this)});
    });

};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. What behavior do you want to be live?  What is the HTML that is being loaded dynamically?  So far, you've just shown a jQuery method, but not shown any use of that method or any HTML that you want it to work with.  We need the other 1/2 of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well it's not the loaded content I'm having problems with, I'm just trying to figure out how to turn this query function into a live function so it will target future DOM elements. The future Dom element is just a basic text box with an ID, sorry if i didn't word it right.

Comment: jQuery methods aren't live, event handlers can be made live.  So, the question still doesn't make sense.  Please describe EXACTLY what problem you're trying to solve, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: ok , the call to the above jquery plugin is: `.charCount()` So i did this: `$('textbox').live( function(){ $('textbox').charCount() });` but it didn't work at all. Thats why i figured i had to go the source . I will however have to update all of my .live() to .on() before i leave my local environment, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery "live" (deprecated) or "on" works just with click, dblclick, keydown, keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and mouseup events.

If you just need to use just `$('selector').live()` use this library:

LiveQuery: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

```
$('selector').livequery(function(){});
```